# Windows sounds play from a selection at random

Tags: windows, system-sounds, wav, bindings

So I'm trying to figure out how to play from my selection of .wav files for a single notification on windows sounds.
Windows will only accept .wav but it needs to be at random from my folder.

I was thinking maybe I could use a dummy .wav file that runs a Self-extracting archive that contains a script for it.
But I have no idea on how to disguise the zip file as a wav file.

I've read there are different binder softwares but I'm trying to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you selecting the .wav file to be played via registry?

You could go about it from the other way around:

You can open a script instead of the .wav file, and let the script choose a random .wav file to play (but you'd have play this file in the background, i imagine).

Or, you can execute a script that selects a random .wav file from your list and renames it to the file to be played - either when the notification appears if that's possible, or you can periodically rename random files.

Comment: I don't think i can do the former.
The latter is doable but how do i create a service that listens for a notification sound?

Comment: How are you selecting the wav to be played in the first place? I didn't have in mind listening to notification sounds - I thought about executing a script before playing a .wav file when the notification appears.

Comment: i will probably write a small script that will return a random wav from a list and then set that to the registry key associated with the sound has played. this way the new file will be ready to play the next time its needed